# How to use css file for image source in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have got a lot of icons for an application and right now its embedded in 
the script tag 
eg:in my script tag i have

```
    [Embed(source="/assets/icons/save_it_icon.png")]

    [Bindable] 

    private var saveIcon:Class;
```

in my flex component :

```
<mx:Image  id ="savePaneImg" source="{saveIcon}" 
        buttonMode="true" 
        toolTip="Save comments" 
        click="doSave();" />
```

How do i move this image source to css file for resusability across 
different components?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source` is not a style property, you cannot set it in css. Instead I recommend you to create class, where all the images will be stored.

```
[Bindable]
public class IconManager {

    [Embed(source="/assets/icons/save_it_icon.png")]
    public static var saveIcon:Class;

}
```

Usage:

```
<mx:Image  id ="savePaneImg" source="{IconManager.saveIcon}" 
            buttonMode="true" 
            toolTip="Save comments" 
            click="doSave();" />
```

Comment: +1 for the binding, but you *could* use a custom meta tag and CSS to manage the resources, only it would have to be at runtime, using reflections, and it would be a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

check this code, this would be help you....

```
public class IconSrc{
  [Embed(source="/assets/icons/save_it_icon.png")] 
  [Bindable]
  private var _icon1:Class
  public static function getSource(icon:String):Class{
    switch(icon){
     case "icon1": return _icon1;break;
      .
      .
      .
    }
  }
}

<mx:Image  id ="savePaneImg" source="{IconSrc.getSource('icon1')}"  
            buttonMode="true"  
            toolTip="Save comments"  
            click="doSave();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check this post
[Howto embed images in Actionscript 3 / Flex 3 the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053546/howto-embed-images-in-actionscript-3-flex-3-the-right-way/1053563#1053563)

Create a Class and store all your assets in there as static variables. Then access them from all over the place.